# ASP.net MVC routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just created below action in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Serial(string letterCase)
{
    string serial = "SAM_ATM_1.0.0";
    if (letterCase == "lower")
    {
        return Content(serial.ToLower());
    }
    return Content(serial);
}
```

and added below routing rules above default action:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Serial",
    url: "serial/{letterCase}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Serial", letterCase = "upper" }
);
```

However calling url http://localhost:5532/home/serial/lower in debug session, `letterCase` is passed with null value.

Comment: Is that the first route in your definitions? And to match it, you need to call `...5532/serial/lower` (or change the route url to `url: "home/serial/{letterCase}"`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Is it possible to write rule such that both /home/serial/lower and /serial/lower work? I tried {controller}/serial/{letterCase} but it will not work without controller name and /serial/lower will lead errors but /home/serial/lower works.

Comment: You can always add 2 route definitions - one for `url: "home/serial/{letterCase}"` and one for `url: "serial/{letterCase}"` (with both `defaults:` being the same)

Comment: @StephenMuecke So there is no option that set controller name as an optional parameter. Am i right?

Comment: No, - you will need 2 route definitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you call  localhost:5532/**home**/serial/lower, try to call localhost:5532/serial/lower

or, if you need localhost:5532/home/serial/lower, rewrite your route rule to

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Serial",
    url: "home/serial/{letterCase}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Serial", letterCase = "upper" }
);
```

Comment: Is it possible to write rule such that both /home/serial/lower and /serial/lower  work? I tried `{controller}/serial/{letterCase}` but it will not work without controller name and `/serial/lower` will lead errors but `/home/serial/lower` works.

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Serial1",
    url: "home/serial/{letterCase}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Serial", letterCase = "upper" }
);

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Serial2",
    url: "serial/{letterCase}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Serial", letterCase = "upper" }
);

Comment: @VSB look at the last my 2 comments